# What is the best practice for using IPTABLES with an Amazon Linux server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables

Amazon has their own port security and IPTABLES is not running by default. Do I need to configure and enable IPTABLES?

Answer (score 8):

## Only Whitelists

Amazon effectively only gives you [whitelisting ability](https://wincent.com/wiki/Using_iptables_on_EC2_instances).

Their [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) points this out directly:

> Security group rules are always permissive; you can't create rules that deny access.

If you want fine-grained control over blacklists or you want to set up port forwarding, using `iptables` is one way to go.

## Examples

Perhaps you want to drop packets from a bot scanning your box

```
$ iptables -I INPUT -s 174.132.223.252 -j DROP
```

You also might want to run an application as a non-root user on an unprivileged port and forward to port 80.

```
$ iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```